# Parse url in windows script

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, url, parser

In a windows bat file how do I parse this url

https://vimeo.com/library/courses/angular-series

to get the text 'angular-series' without the single quotes of course

Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Read and apply [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html); use next code snippet in a `.bat` or `.cmd` script:

```
for %%g in ("https://vimeo.com/library/courses/angular-series") do echo %%~nxg
```

Of course, instead of `ECHO`ing resulting string, you could save it to a variable:

```
for %%g in ("https://vimeo.com/library/courses/angular-series") do set "_URL_leaf=%%~nxg"
echo %_URL_leaf%
```

**Output** from `cmd` command prompt:

```
==> for %g in ("https://vimeo.com/library/courses/angular-series") do @echo %~nxg
angular-series

==>
```